# Django postres methods for external Database

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I am working in a Django app for investors. Currently using a database and 3 installed apps configured in the settings.py.

I am about integrating a new feature for which every broker will register their IP in our app, so that we will replicate our postgres database in their server (Everything is same except 'HOST' regarding with database) manually. Then broker will send GET and POST methods to our server from their server.

I need to switch the database based on the request coming. I think I can connect their postgres database dynamically by looking the request and process by SQL queries. My requirement is, I just need to use Django postgres methods for processing without configuring the database in settings file.

if configuring database in settings is the only way, how can I switch to database every time efficiently and how many databases can be connected in a single Django app?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you want to use Django methods (and not simply use RAW SQL queries and parse them) you will have to use the settings.py method and define all your databases there.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/multi-db/

In short, you define a database and can manually chose it in your code via (as per docs):

```
Author.objects.using(database_name_variable).filter(...)
```

An alternative would be to look at using REST api (like Tastypie) to make calls to different Django instances connected to each database.

Comment: is there any limit to connect databases in Django?